# MYSQL show mix data from a column with pagination

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with following tables

| ID | Name | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 | 1 |
| 2 | Name2 | 1 |
| 3 | Name3 | 1 |
| 4 | Name4 | 2 |
| 5 | Name5 | 1 |
| 6 | Name6 | 1 |
| 7 | Name7 | 2 |

So I want to fetch 3 results at a time like this

```
Select * from table limit 0,3
```

But I want mix results from the third column. So when possible all 3 records should contain 2 results from type=1 and 1 result from type=2

This will be dynamic which means more types can be added and may LIMIT 10 can have (2,3,2,1,2) data.

Comment: Hi @Girish Please provide expected output.

Comment: ID (1,2,4) should be returned in the first page and next page will show similar mixed results

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY makes no sense. *But I want mix results from the third column. So when possible all 3 records should contain 2 results from type=1 and 1 result from type=2* Build according ordering expression which will provide such sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number items of each type separately

```
select ID, Name, Type
from (
   select *, row_number() over(partition by Type order by Name) rn
   from mytable
) t
order by rn, id
limit 0,3
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f719f6601774f591ce7ab79f3574e41)

Returns two rows of type=1 and one row of type=2.

```
ID  Name    Type
1   Name1   1
4   Name4   2
2   Name2   1
```

Comment: This will provide equal rows amount per value whereas OP needs them in a certain proportion.

Comment: @serg tried same query. not working for me

Comment: @Girish, added the fiddle. What is wrong with the result?